# Generic service routing rule with Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to make a generic route rule to my services using Spring Cloud Gateway and Consul. Services are correctly registered in Consul and the Gateway is finding them with no problem.

The problem is, I want to make a generic rule to match my services. For example, I do have a hello-service and goodbye-service and the following RouteLocator on my gateway:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ConsulGatewayApplication {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                      .route(r -> r.path("/hello-service/**")
                                   .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
                                   .uri("lb://hello-service")
                            )
                      .route(r -> r.path("/goodbye-service/**")
                                   .filters(f -> f.stripPrefix(1))
                                   .uri("lb://goodbye-service")
                            )


                   .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsulGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now Image an environment with a lot of microservices, with the current solution I have to make a routing rule for each of them.

What I want is make a generic and more simple routing rule, something like a wild card. If the path contains *-service, it should send to the specified service, such as:

- If the path is /a-service/, it should route to the a-service;
- If the path is /b-service/, it should route to the b-service and so on;

Without explicit making a rule for a-service and b-service.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to automatically add routes via discovery client. Check the docs. I'm on holiday so can't go into more detail today

Comment: Hey @spencergibb thanks, I've found it on the [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_discoveryclient_route_definition_locator). Got it working, thank you for pointing me out, I was lost were to starting search :)

Comment: Great! Glad you found it